# dc.js chart.select function

Tags: pie-chart, dc.js

I am new to dc.js. And I refer to the API Reference and see the chart.select function. But I do not know how to use it.

Such as I have a piechart and I want to have the value and percentage showing in the div below the chart. Could some one tell me if this can be realized using chart.select?

Answer (score 2):

`chart.select` is for selecting some elements in the d3 or CSS selector sense, if you want to apply some attributes. It probably won't help you directly.

What you are probably looking for is the `filtered` event, which will tell you when items have been selected. Then you can read the filters and display them elsewhere like so:

```
chart.on('filtered.some_id', function() {
    d3.select('#your-div').text(chart.filters().join(','));
});
```

(There are also ways to respond directly to interaction events, but I think this is more to the point for what you're trying to do.)